# FromUri parameters are blank

Tags: c#

I am attempting to send a list of parameters using FromURI, however they are all blank when received.

For example, the query string is:

```
http://localhost:64753/api/X/GetX?XSearch.MemberID=N1020&XSearch.FirstName=John&XSearch.LastName=Doe
```

Which is being sent to:

```
 public List<XDTO> GetX([FromUri] DataContract.ServiceRequest.XSearch X)
 {
     //Code here.
 }
```

With "XSearch" being:

```
public class XSearch: SearchRequest
{
    public String MemberID { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I put a breakpoint within "GetX' and MemberID, FirstName and LastName of "X" are all null.  I'm expecting them to populated by the query string (MemberID = N1020, FirstName = John, LastName = Doe).

If anything needs clarification feel free to ask, I know I'm not great at asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the prefix of class name for your query string keys. Model binding/Formatters don't care about it for the root level container.

Try the following URL:

```
http://localhost:64753/api/X/GetX?MemberID=N1020&FirstName=John&LastName=Doe
```